# How does The Machine handle identical twins?

Tags: person-of-interest

The Machine's main source of identity seems to be the SSN, and any other identity cards that is linked to the SSN like driving license, company identity cards, etc. It then uses the photo on ID for face recognition.

My question is what happens with identical twins?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### With ease

Identical twins are not truly identical. Although they possess the same DNA — the same blueprint for development — that does not mean that they developed identically. Differing position in the uterus can lead to differing forces on the monozygotic fetuses, or different hormonal levels.  Once born, the babies may further be exposed to differing levels of nutrition or other environmental stimuli that affect the development of facial features.

More than that, in fact: Modern, non-fictional facial recognition technology can distinguish between "identical" monozygotic twins. As indicated in [this paper](http://www.cse.msu.edu/biometrics/Publications/Face/KlarePaulinoJain_AnalysisFacialFeaturesIdenticalTwins_IJCB11.pdf), researchers were able to discriminate between pairs of identical twins, although the precise feature that distinguished them varied from pair to pair.

[image: A linear-logarithmic graph showing true acceptance rate (ranging from 0 to 1) against false acceptance rate (ranging from one thousandths to a tenth.) There are two lines on the graph, for two different methods, both showing the facial recognition is good at distinguishing twins facial data.]

For example, as indicated in the previous graph (taken from the [same paper](http://www.cse.msu.edu/biometrics/Publications/Face/KlarePaulinoJain_AnalysisFacialFeaturesIdenticalTwins_IJCB11.pdf)), in the model that the researchers examined, if the likelihood of incorrectly identifying two faces as the same (i.e. confusing one twin for another) is about 1/100, the likelihood of correctly doing so is around 50%. This is substantially worse than the likelihood for non-twins, but still pretty good.

**This is all with modern, unsophisticated facial recognition algorithms. A sophisticated AI such as the Machine could outperform the best humans. And humans who are familiar with a person's facial features can far outperform the 50% accuracy given in the cited paper. It is very plausible that the Machine could distinguish between supposedly "identical" twins without any trouble.**

Answer (score 1):

Your DMV photos would be ideal. She would likely know the exact type of camera used, the color temperature of the lights installed in the building, and the date to know the ambient conditions (and *god* knows what else).

> *Distinguishing Identical Twins by Face Recognition*
>
> **The  best performance  was  observed  when  all  images  of  a  pair  of identical  twins  were  taken  on  the  same  day  in  the  studio environment and the twins had a neutral expression.** For this case,  the  best  performing  algorithm  had  a  90%  confidence interval  for  the  **EER  from  0.01  to  0.04.**
>
> The  corresponding confidence  interval  for  the  same  day  with  ambient  light and  neutral  expression  was  **0.12  to  0.21.**  For  cross-year recognition,  the  best  90%  confidence  interval  for  the  EER was from **0.15 to 0.27.**
>
> Performance also showed that gender does not effect performance and that there is an age effect. The results showed that it is easier to distinguish twins over 40 year old than twins under 40.
>
> <sub>–P. Jonathon Phillips, Patrick J. Flynn, Kevin W. Bowyer, Richard W. Vorder Bruegge, Patrick J. Grother, George W. Quinn, Matthew Pruitt. [www3.nd.edu pdf](http://www3.nd.edu/%7Ekwb/PhillipsEtAlFG_2011.pdf)</sub>

---

> Abbreviated as **EER**. A biometric security system predetermines the threshold values for its *false acceptance rate* and its *false rejection rate*, and when the rates are equal, the common value is referred to as the *equal error rate*. The value indicates that the proportion of false acceptances is equal to the proportion of false rejections. **The lower the equal error rate value, the higher the accuracy** of the biometric system. –[webopedia.com](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/E/equal_error_rate.html)

I don't exactly understand how to interpret an EER (as a percentage?) but The Machine would **compare pictures taken under the closest matching conditions**: with the same expression (ideally, none) and indoor lighting, to reduce the EER as much as possible.

Note that the ERR increases by an order of magnitude when using ambient lighting, as opposed to a studio environment. Whereas a lapse of one year between photos was only a small increase.

Don't forget that this study had a control, in that the same camera was used, but She can probably compensate if it's not. I assume She is quite capable of reverse-engineering what a particular piece of hardware was used from its result, e.g., a photo.

Besides, we're talking about an A.I. that was built to deduce. She probably has an EER of .001 at a 99% confidence interval.